# IIS7.5 redirecting non www to www also with https

Tags: redirect, iis-7.5

I am trying to configure my IIS to redirect all none www calls to www calls including https
That first part is quite easy, but i have not found a solution that will also work when you have https enabled on your bindings.

So I would like both 
http://domain.com/ 
and 
https://domain.com/ 
and 
http://www.domain.com/ 
to all be redirected to :

https://www.domain.com/

any suggestions?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
This ended up working for me:

<rewrite>
        <rules>                                 
            <rule name="HTTP to HTTPS redirect" stopProcessing="true">
              <match url="(.*)" />
                <conditions>
                  <add input="{HTTPS}" pattern="off" ignoreCase="true" />
                </conditions>
              <action type="Redirect" redirectType="Found" url="https://{HTTP_HOST}/{R:1}" />
            </rule>
        </rules>        
    </rewrite>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<rewrite>
      <rules>
      <rule name="Non www HTTP to HTTPS" patternSyntax="ECMAScript" stopProcessing="true">
              <match url="(.*)" />
              <conditions>
                  <add input="{HTTPS}" pattern="off" />
                  <add input="{HTTP_HOST}" pattern="^www" negate="true" />
              </conditions>
              <action type="Redirect" url="https://www.{HTTP_HOST}{REQUEST_URI}" />
          </rule>
          <rule name="Non www HTTPS to www HTTPS" patternSyntax="ECMAScript" stopProcessing="true">
              <match url="(.*)" />
              <conditions>
                  <add input="{HTTPS}" pattern="On" />
                  <add input="{HTTP_HOST}" pattern="^www" negate="true" />
              </conditions>
              <action type="Redirect" url="https://www.{HTTP_HOST}{REQUEST_URI}" />
          </rule>
          <rule name="HTTP to HTTPS" stopProcessing="true">
              <match url="(.*)" />
              <conditions>
                  <add input="{HTTPS}" pattern="off" />
                  <add input="{HTTP_HOST}" pattern="www*" />
              </conditions>
              <action type="Redirect" url="https://{HTTP_HOST}{REQUEST_URI}" />
          </rule>
      </rules>
  </rewrite>
```

Comment: I still have a problem.
If you go here:
https://www.skaljakke.dk/skaljakker-damer
it all seems fine, but if you remove the "www." it will fail. Do you any suggestions?

Comment: @user3305839 Do you have a SSL certificate that covers both www. and just domain.com ?  The web server has to be able to first do the handshake, then the redirect.  If you don't have a cert that covers both, the browser detects a security exception.

Answer (score 0):

@Josh: Your answer works for the first request.
It will end up with "https://www", perfect.
But if i then remove "www." from the address, it will fail like the image below.

[image: Resulting page in Firefox]